# How can I set the MySQL date with string like 2015-07-30 18:32:18

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to set a record in mysql table. It goes like this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE posts SET creatdate = $timestring WHERE postid = 1 ");
```

I get $timestring from anther record in this table:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($table)){

    $timestring = $row['creatdate'];
```

and

```
echo $timestring;
```

get

```
2015-07-30 18:32:18
```

why can't I set this record

Comment: put single quotes around $timestring

Comment: In mysql, if your variable is a string, you have to put quote. So do as fallow : `mysql_query("UPDATE posts SET creatdate = '$timestring' WHERE postid = 1 ");`

Comment: Please _Stop using the **deprecated** `mysql` extension_. Read [***the red warning box***  at the top](http://php.net/mysql_connect). Learn about injection, prepared statements and learn to use either `PDO` or `mysqli` (the `i` of which stands for _improved_). and yes, amdixon is right: quote the string, something you could've found out by checking the return value of `mysql_error`... debugging is as much a part of programming as writing code is

Comment: It works, thank you dude! @amdixon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place quotes around your date i.e. `$timestring` as

```
"UPDATE posts SET creatdate = '$timestring' WHERE postid = 1 "
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add quotes around your date `$timestring`.

Try

```
mysql_query("UPDATE posts SET creatdate = '$timestring' WHERE postid = 1 ");
```

You can also use `mysql` built in function `NOW()`

```
mysql_query("UPDATE posts SET creatdate = NOW() WHERE postid = 1 ");
```